# How to hide the encrypted version of a file put in a cryptfs filesystem?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption, ecryptfs

Say I create an encrypted folder and add a file to it:

```
# mount -t ecryptfs /srv /srv
# echo word > /srv/file
```

The content of file is `unavailable` only after unmounting the filesystem.

How can I configure `ecryptfs` (or use an alternative encryption system on Linux) to avoid having the content of file unencrypted at any time?

---

One possibility is is run a script that mounts and umounts the `ecryptfs` filesystem everytime a file is added but the mount password have to be given which creates security risks.

Answer (score 1):

General answer (as my expert knowledge is AIX EFS, not linux)

When talking about encrypted files - you must distinguish between 'stored' and 'in memory'. What I expect you are experiencing is that the file contents are 'in memory' in clear text - while (I am sure) they are encrypted 'on disk aka stored' or also called - 'at rest'.

Test for you to perform:
* as non-root userA add a file to your encrypted filesystem, mode 644
* as non-root userB - you are not expected to know the encryption key, so ideally you cannot see the 'clear text', better is no access.
* as root, ideally, no access (without decryption key), worst case, can see the encrypted data.

On AIX, so I shall assume that Linux is the same: you will need to have some credentials that allow you to access (the secret key used to encrypt/decrypt) the 'at rest' data and/or access cached representation of same 'in cached memory' data - above and beyond the traditional *NIX DAC access mechanisms.

However, my assumption may be wrong. If Linux is doing encryption per partition rather than per file - having access to the encrypted partition could imply that the only remaining protection is by the classic DAC and/or ACL mechanisms (e.g., extras coming via SELinux and/or AppArmor)

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain an encrypted filesystem is what you want in this use case.

Why not use an `alias` (see [man alias](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html)) to make use of the `gpg` tool (see [man gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html)) to decrypt/encrypt the specified file/folder on open/close?

Example of this can be found @ [my gist page](https://gist.github.com/jas-/be27795041ee158087a21844dd908cad) (working example)

While I know this may not be the most ideal solution it should provide a means to encrypt/decrypt file/folders only when needed vs. mounting a disk and leaving the file/folders decrypted at all times.